# Why didn't the Kill-T-Gang drain (and kill) Akari's Libido during the Oberon's battle?

Tags: tropes, captain-earth

Amara told Daichi that Capt. Manatsu (Daichi's father) died before crashing into his Kill-T-Gang form: he drained the Libido (lifeforce) out of the spaceman.

It is stated mid-series that merely approaching a Kill-T-Gang can have this effect, and its range is estimated in the 10,000 kilometers (because it could drain the whole planet by just landing on it).

It is also stated that the Neoteny are immune because of their connection to their Livlasters.

During the Oberon fight (ep.24), the four Knights are seen battling the Kill-T-Gang, but only three of them are Neoteny; Akari is just a ordinary human.

The Kill-T-Gang are far from the Blume (and Akari is pegged to the OUTSIDE of the ship), but at most a dozen kilometers.

Besides some trope being applied here to justify this Fiat, shouldn't Akari die?

What is protecting her?